# Inverting y = b^x mod p given knowledge of y, b, x and prime p?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose I have:

y = b^x mod p

and I also know the values of b, x and p, and p is also prime.

Is there a closed-form way to find z such that y^z = b mod p?

Comment: more or less. Find a principal root of $p,$ call that $r.$ This means there are solutions $c,d$ to $r^c \equiv b$ and $r^d \equiv y.$ These are called the orders, traditional word was index. If $c,d$ compare favorably ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** The following is actually the algorithm assuming $b$ is unknown.  It will find an answer for $z$ under the assumption that $x$ and $p-1$ are relatively prime (which is a necessary and sufficient condition for unknown $b$).  To see how knowledge of $b$ can change the problem, see the first comment to this post.

---

Note that $$b \equiv y^z \equiv b^{xz} \pmod{p}$$ which is true if $$xz \equiv 1 \pmod{(p-1)}$$ which can in turn be solved for $z$ relatively efficiently by the extended euclidean algorithm.

Comment: You state "Note that $b \equiv y^z \equiv b^{xz} \pmod{p}$ which is true if and only if $xz \equiv 1 \pmod{(p-1)}$ ...". However, if $b = 2, x = 5, p = 31$, then $y \equiv b^x = 32 \equiv 1 \pmod{31}$. Thus, there's no solution for $y^z \equiv b \pmod p$. Also, for $b \equiv b^{xz} \pmod p$, if $b = 2, x = 2, z = 3$, then $b^{xz} \equiv 2^6 = 64 \equiv 2 \pmod{31}$, but $xz = 6 \not\equiv 1 \pmod{30}$. The $p-1$ needs to be replaced by the [Multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $b$ modulo $p$, but note this value always divides into $p - 1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the criticism.  My gut was telling me the algorithm should be more complicated, but I didn't think more about it at the time.  Let me see if I can save it...